# Visual Studio 2017 and Arduino

Tags: visual-studio

I'm developing a quiz system on vb (vs2017) triggered by four Arduino controlled buttons (UNO).

When the cycle is over (playing time) the system must return to the initial screen and restart the game. So far so good, but when I press the button, the system can not read the buttons that are pressed anymore. It is as if it had lost the connection with the Arduino.

My code:

```
Imports System

Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class FrAbrir

    Dim comPORT As String = "COM4"
    Dim receivedData As Integer

    Private Sub FrAbrir_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If (comPORT <> "") Then
            SerialPort1.Close()
            SerialPort1.PortName = comPORT
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
            SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
            SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
            SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
            SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
            SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
            SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 10000
            SerialPort1.Open()
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Porta COM4 não encontrada. Verifique a ligação com o Arduíno.")
        End If

    End Sub

    Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
        Dim Incoming As String
        Try
            Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Return "nothing" & vbCrLf
            Else
                Return Incoming
            End If
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
        End Try

    End Function


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Try
            receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
            SerialPort1.Open()
        Catch

        End Try

        If receivedData = 1 Or receivedData = 2 Or receivedData = 3 Or receivedData = 4 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            receivedData = 0
            SerialPort1.Close()
            FrIdJogador.Show()
            Me.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Someone could help saying where I'm going wrong to reestablish the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i discovered what's going on. In another formulary the connection still opened. So, I insert the line **serialport1.close()** and it's working very well.
Thanks!